# Injecting variable value from js to html file

Tags: javascript, html

I want use my variable, which is in JavaScript file, but I want to use that in my html file.
Is this possible?
This is my JavaScript file

```js
var dev = 'development';
var mas = 'master';
var check = process.env.BRANCH_NAME;
var check1 = process.env.JOB_NAME;
if (check = dev) {
    var str = 'dev key';
} else if (check = mas) {
    var str = 'master key';
} else {
    var str = 'live key';
}
```

I want to use the `str` variable in a html file

```html
<script>
var str='';
</script>
```

How can I inject my variable value from JavaScript file in to a html file?

Comment: Are you actually trying an assignment instead of a conditional expression? `if (check = dev)`

Comment: You can include the file in your html, and make it available: `<script src="your_js_file.js"></script>`

Comment: Call your javascript file before you html file script, make variable global 
 before assignment and then html script will have access to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With JavaScript, the global scope is the complete JavaScript environment. In HTML, the global scope is the window object. All global variables belong to the window object. ([W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp))

You just need to reference your variable to the `window`; global variables are defined in the `window` object in JavaScript, so every global variable can be accessed from the `window` element like this:

```
var foo = 'bar';
console.log (window.foo); // outputs: bar
```

In your case you could set the variable as global, from you external file:

```
window.str = 'anything';
```

Or if you use inmediate functions to initialize you script, you could define a context as an parameter and pass `window` as a argument:

```
(function (context) {
    context.str = 'anything';
})(window);
```

In both cases you don’t have to define the variable in your html.

Another option, if you are not running `strict mode` is to define the variable without the `var`; that will create a global variable. This will work if no prior definition of the variable is assigned in the global scope.

```
str = 'anything';
```

As a side note, if you don’t use inmediate functions to initialize your script in your external JavaScript files, the variables defined in such file will be defined as global.

More about [variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

Comment: Good! Glad i could help! :)

Comment: thanks once again.you saved me from my Team lead's anger

Answer (score -1):

You could make an object from this variable and use this object wherever you want.

**JS:**

```
    var str = str || {};      
    var dev = 'development';
    var mas = 'master';
    var check = process.env.BRANCH_NAME;
    var check1 = process.env.JOB_NAME;
    if (check = dev) {
        str.key = 'dev key';
    } else if (check = mas) {
        str.key = 'master key';
    } else {
        str.key = 'live key';
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<script>
    str.key = '';
</script>
```

Comment: i think it is corect but i dont know it will work or not. i mark this as my answer

Comment: This will *always* set `str.key = 'dev key'` and then set `str.key = ''` in the script in the html file.

Comment: @Archer no, not if the JS file was loaded before.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the scenario I am explaining.  It will do exactly as I describe above and can do nothing else.  Your if statement **_sets_** the value of `check` to the value of `dev` and then the script in your html **_sets_** the value of `str.key` to an empty string.